# Does a new thread have full memory-visibility of all other threads' previous actions on shared objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, memory-model

I have thread **A** maintaining a data structure (adding, deleting, changing values in a **ConcurrentHashMap**).

I have thread **B** listening on a socket and occasionally creating thread **C** to handle a new client connection.

All thread **C**s will only ever read from the **ConcurrentHashMap** maintained by thread **A** (never update it).

Is thread **C** guaranteed to see all updates that were performed by thread **A**, on the **ConcurrentHashMap**, before thread **C** was created/ started by thread **B**?

(Edited last sentence to make question clearer: only concerned about updates to the ConcurrentHashMap.)

Comment: Yes, subject to the happens-before provisions of the Java Memory Model *(q.v.)*. Basically you need to make sure every access is `synchronized` or the `java.util.concurrent` equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is thread C guaranteed to see all updates that were performed by thread A before thread C was created/ started by thread B?

In general (for example, with an ordinary `HashMap`), No.

But (again in general) if thread C was created by thread A, then the answer would be yes.

(There is a *happens-before* relation between one thread calling `start()` on a thread object, and the start of the new thread's `run()` method.  But you have introduced a third thread ... and have not described anything that would give you a *happens-before* chain from A to B to C.)

---

However, you are talking about a `ConcurrentHashMap` here, and concurrent maps have innate memory consistency:

> "Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a `ConcurrentMap` as a key or value happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the `ConcurrentMap` in another thread."

(From the `ConcurrentMap` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).)

So, for anything where multiple threads are sharing a `ConcurrentHashMap` a read-only thread is guaranteed to see updates made by another one ... modulo the documented behavior of iterators.

Comment: Thankyou for this comprehensive answer. My question was poorly phrased, I should have mentioned thread C only reading from the ConcurrentHashMap rather than asking if any updates would have been visible (implying possible updates to non-concurrent objects).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as stated in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update
>   operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update
>   operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any
>   (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If the `ConcurrentHashMap` object is shared globally or passed/shared to/with `thread C` .

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> performed by thread A before thread C was created/ started by thread B?

deals with an ill-defined concept because Java Memory Model doesn't provide any guarantees based on time ordering. You have to ensure a *happens-before* ordering either through program order or through synchronization order and you seem to be doing neither.

So, to answer your question with "no" would be wrong because the question has a false hidden assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this, I want to add something, Dariusz don't you think for updated values we can use volatile modifier.

Correct me if I am wrong volatile variables always return its updated value.